# Zurb foundation joyride tip location 'right'/ 'left'

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-joyride

I am using Zurb-foundation 5 Joyride for a tour guide. It has been pretty helpful. I have a div split into few vertical divs. I was trying to display an info for each vertical div but those tips are coming at the bottom/ top instead of coming at right/ left.

```
demo
```

http://codepen.io/chetang/full/pAvmf/

The docs aren't clear on how to achieve it. Any suggestions!!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define the location patterns in joyride before using them as shown below.

```
$(document).foundation({
   joyride : {
   tip_location: 'top',
   nub_position: 'auto',
   tip_location_patterns    : {
   top: ['top'],
   bottom: [], // bottom should not need to be repositioned
   left: ['right', 'top', 'bottom'],
   right: ['left', 'top', 'bottom']
 },
}
});
```

For more clarity Visit http://codepen.io/Parteek/pen/ohHlc.

Comment: It moves the tip to the top of div. I want them beside the divs (either right or left).